# <?php wp_link_pages(); ?> is working on posts but not on pages to display pagination

Tags: wordpress

I created a theme from scratch and have pagination working on the post pages using , it's working on single.php.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php  

while(have_posts()) {
    the_post();
?>
  <div class="mainConent">
    <div class="leftSidebar">
        <div class="sidebarTitleWrapper">
          <?php dynamic_sidebar('left_sidebar') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="recentBlogsWrapper">
    <div class="blogWrapper">
      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
      <p><?php the_time('F j, Y') ?></p>
      <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
          <div class="card-image">
              <img class="page-image" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>" alt="Card Image">
          </div>
      <?php } ?>
      <div class="card-description">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
        <?php comments_template(); ?>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="backarrowwrap">
          <a class="backhomelink" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>" <?php if(is_front_page()) echo 'class="active"' ?>>
            <img class="backarrow" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/backarrow.png" alt="back arrow" />
            Go Back Home
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightSidebar" id="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebarTitleWrapper">
          <?php dynamic_sidebar('right_sidebar') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I put it right below the_content(); and it's working exactly like I want it to. However, it's not working on page.php, even though it's in the same place on the page.

```
<?php get_header();

while(have_posts()) {
    the_post();
?>
  <div class="pageWrapper">
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
        <div class="card-image">
            <img class="page-image" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>" alt="Card Image">
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="card-description">
       <?php the_content(); ?>
       <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I've included the

```
<!–-nextpage-–>
```

code in one of my pages just like I did for the blogs, but it's not paginating between the paragraphs.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you use `<!–-nextpage-–>` or `<!--nextpage-->`? Look carefully and see the difference in the characters.

Comment: @Matt it's working fine for me in default WP Twenty Twenty theme

Comment: We didn't found anything wrong in the code, its working well at our end

Comment: Try using this code in default theme

Comment: How many pages have you got?

Answer (score 0):

You need at least `one <!--nextpage-->`, if the content of a page (or post) has at least one `<!--nextpage-->` tag (and this code is in The Loop), this prints linked page numbers **(“Pages: 1 2 3 4 and so on...”)**, without a link on current page number, and by default within

tags:.